In how far is the Lyapunov spectrum characteristic for a dynamic system?
If two dynamic systems have the same Lyapunov spectrum on their respective attractor (of equal dimension, of course), which results relate to the properties of these two dynamic systems on those attractors?
I know that the Lyapunov spectrum is related to the entropy and fractal dimension of the attractor. But i am more interested about (differential-) topological and quantitative properties.
